# Passando dados via post HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, undefined

Ola, estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade, um controle academico, e ao tentar remover uma tupla do banco de dados passando o "id" da tupla via formulario post, o valor chega ou vazio ou undefined. Segue o código:

```
<tbody>
            <%for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){%>
                <tr>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><%=lista[i].matricula%></td>
                    <td><%=lista[i].nome%></td>
                    <td><%=lista[i].IRA%></td>
                    <td><%=lista[i].codCurso%></td>
                    <td><%=lista[i].endereco%></td>
                    <td><button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" src"admin/alteraAluno" href="admin/formAluno">Editar</button></td>
                    <td>
                        <form  action="removeAluno" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name"matricula" value="<%= lista[i]%>"/>
                            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">Remover</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <%}%>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Aqui em cima tem uma tabela e dois botões, um para alterar, ainda não implementado, e um de remoção que ao chegar no javascript chega vazio ou undefined

```
  var removeAlunoUniversidade = function(req, res){
    var connection = app.infra.connectionFactory();
    var adminDAO = new app.infra.AdminDAO(connection);

    var lista = res.body;

    console.log(lista);

    adminDAO.removeAlunoUniversidade(lista, function(err, result){
        res.redirect('listaAlunos');
    });

    connection.end();
};

app.post('/admin/removeAluno', removeAlunoUniversidade);
```

Gostaria de saber no que estou errando e se há alguma outra forma de fazer isso.

Comment: não sei se seu código está idêntico, mas seu input está faltando com erro, está `name"matricula"`.... altere pra `name="matricula"`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, detalhe passou despercebido! agr ele n ta removendo do banco, segue função:   
    AdminDAO.prototype.removeAlunoUniversidade = function(matricula, callback){
    console.log(matricula);
    this._connection.query('DELETE FROM  aluno WHERE `aluno`.`matricula` set ?', matricula, callback);
}

Comment: Tudo resolvido!